# Dailymotion Advertising Api

Tags: html, api, ads, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to get status about my video with dailymotion api. Some of videos are not getting ads. So i'm trying to understand how it's gonna be.

I tried like this but it's not telling about ads status.

```
String.Format("https://api.dailymotion.com/user/{0}/videos?fields=id,title,partner&limit=100&page={1}", userID, pageNumber)
```

i thought like partner key is enough to understand that situation but it's not. Can someone help me ? Also i tried to get something from http code but it didn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't know if ads will be displayed or not on a video. The AD server uses many criteria to determine what to do.
When the player is loaded on the page, a call to the ad server is sent in real time to know if an ad is available or not.
The API player provides some useful ad events, maybe you can use them: [api events documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-api-events)